# How should approved scopes be returned from an OAuth2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0

Specifying an [API for library patrons](http://gbv.github.com/paia/), compatible with OAuth2.0, I stumbled across **[OAuth scopes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.3)**. The OAuth2.0 specification seems to be interpreted differently at some points, for instance [GitHub uses commas](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes) to delimit scopes while Google uses spaces, as defined in RFC 6749. The RFCs tells:

> If the issued access token scope
> is different from the one requested by the client, the authorization
> server MUST include the "scope" response parameter to inform the
> client of the actual scope granted

But no scope response parameter is mentioned later in the specification. In particular I want to implement [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) (section 4.3.). This example of a response is given in the OAuth2.0 specification:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Cache-Control: no-store
 Pragma: no-cache

 {
   "access_token":"2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA",
   "token_type":"example",
   "expires_in":3600,
   "refresh_token":"tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA",
   "example_parameter":"example_value"
 }
```

Should I include the scopes as space-separated list, as comma-separated list or as JSON arary?

```
 {
   "scope": [ "read", "write", "foobar" ],
   "access_token":"2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA",
   "token_type":"example",
   "expires_in":3600,
   "refresh_token":"tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA",
   "example_parameter":"example_value"
 }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My interpretation of RFC 6749 is that the scopes should be specified as a string containing a space-separated list. The standard is somewhat open to interpretation because of the lack of an example.

```
"scope": "read write foobar"
```

RFC 6749 Section 4.3.3 Access Token Response says:

> If the access token request is valid and authorized, the authorization
>   server issues an access token and optional refresh token as described
>   in Section 5.1.

RFC 6749 Section 5.1 says:

> scope
>            OPTIONAL, if identical to the scope requested by the client;
>            otherwise, REQUIRED.  The scope of the access token as
>            described by Section 3.3.

RFC 6749 Section 3.3 says:

> scope       = scope-token *( SP scope-token )

Comment: I got a confirmation on that question from the OAuth list, indeed it is "space separated". See the discussion starting at http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/oauth/current/msg12326.html